# How do I create a new file on a remote host in fabric (python deployment tool)?

Tags: python, bash, fabric

I'd like to create a file with the name passenger_wsgi.py on a remote host. I'd like to use the following string to create the file's content:

```
'''
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects/project")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
''' % (user,host,user,host)
```

The user and host variables would be parameters of the fabric function.

I'm a total newbie to any sort of file manipulation in python, but also I'm not really sure what the procedure should be in fabric. Should I be creating the file locally and then uploading it with fabric's put command (and removing the local version afterwards)? Should I be creating the file on the remote host with an appropriate bash command (using fabric's run)? If so, then how is it best to deal with all the " and ' in the string - will fabric escape it? Or should I be tackling this in some different manner?

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this in the current Fabric2?  They removed upload_template :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `append()` or `upload_template()` functions from [fabric.contrib.files](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html)

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but this sounds like exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 44):

Use StringIO with put:

```
text = '''
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects/project")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
''' % (user, host, user, host)

import StringIO
put(StringIO.StringIO(text), "remote-path")
```

Comment: Great trick.  The docs don't say anything about passing a file-like object to put--they say you need to provide a path.  I passed up the 'put' command after reading the docs because of that.

Comment: newest docs confirm this: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/fabric/fabric/symbols/python/fabric/operations/put

Comment: @amwinter, that link 404's - new link is: http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put

Comment: @Prisoner *that* link also seems to be dead.

Comment: "local_path may alternately be a file-like object, such as the result of open('path') or a StringIO instance."
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put

Answer (score 2):

What I do is have the file locally as something like "app.wsgi.template".

I then use tokens in the file, like:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/$HOST$/www/$HOST$/django-projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/$HOST$/www/$HOST$/django-projects/project")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I use fabric to "put" the file over to the remote host, then use "sed" (or equivalent functions in Python) to replace the "$HOST$" and "$USER$" tokens with the values I want.

```
run("sed -i backup -e 's/$USER$/%s' -e 's/$HOST$/%s' app.wsgi.template" % (user, host))
run("mv app.wsgi.template app.wsgi")
```

Comment: Thanks :) It's interesting to see how others deal with this sort of thing!

Answer (score -1):

StringIO with put works with a little bit of editing. Try this:

```
put(StringIO.StringIO(
'''
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects/project")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
''' % (user,host,user,host)), "remote-path")
```

if you have an issue with permissions, try this:

```
put(StringIO.StringIO(
'''
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/ruby/%s/www/%s/django-projects/project")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
''' % (user,host,user,host)), "remote-path", use_sudo=True)
```

Comment: This is almost a copy of another answer verbatim. The only additions I can see are using the class `StringIO` instead of the module `StringIO` and the `use_sudo` portion.  I think this belongs in a comment on the source answer, not as its own answer.

Comment: ...admittedly, the class portion (which you didn't emphasize) is very important as it will fail as written in the other answer without a particular import statement...

Comment: `put()` uploads a file, given a filename, not given the raw file content.