# Fabric - Save file on the server and not my laptop

Tags: python, fabric

So in one of the fab task I'm trying to save a file on the server its running on and not on my laptop. 
So this saves file.txt on my laptop's /tmp I want to save it on the server's /tmp

```
with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines("\n".join(names))
    f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fabric.operations.put`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html?highlight=put#fabric.operations.put) command. It uploads a file to remote host.

```
from fabric.context_managers import cd
from fabric.operations import put

with cd('/path/in/remote/host/'):
    put('/path/to/local/file.txt', 'file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to upload. This is creating a list of names. The list comes out ok but it saved on my laptop. I want it to save it on the server the fab task is currently running on.

Comment: You can get the list of names, save it local, that uploda it. There is a question similar to yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114712/how-do-i-create-a-new-file-on-a-remote-host-in-fabric-python-deployment-tool)

Answer (score 0):

you can you [append](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html)

or just by using [run](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html) like this -

```
for name in names:
    command = "echo {} >> /tmp/file.txt".format(name)
    run(command)
```